# Adding event handler to a cocoa button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have a very simple Mac App built with XCode 4 (just a blank form for now).
Now I've added a button via Interface Builder and a method to my AppDelegate:

```
-(IBAction) btnScanClicked
{
    NSLog(@"Hello!");
}
```

When I start my App I get the following message:

> Could not connect the action btnScanClicked: to target of class
>   AppDelegate

Does that mean I can't add any event handlers to my AppDelegate? Where else could I put them, and how would I set that up with Interface Builder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't declared the action method properly. Replace the definition with:

```
-(IBAction) btnScanClicked:(id)sender {
```

Notice how the error message states that it couldn't connect to `btnScanClicked:` That colon at the end isn't punctuation - it's says that the message takes a parameter.

Unlike `UIKit` action methods need to be of the form:

```
- (void)methodName:(id)sender
```

`IBAction` just resolves to `void`, but is an indicator to Interface builder that it is an method that can be hooked up by context dragging.